# Csv Helper Fluent Class Mapping adds a leading zero to int field when mapped to string property

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper, leading-zero

I have a string property called TimeClockCode. Which is mapped to index(0) of the csv file. Index(0) contains integers such as 11565. But after mapping to string TimeClockCode,

Like this:
`Map(p => p.TimeclockCode).Index(0);`

or like this:
`Map(p => p.TimeclockCode).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<string>(0));`

both result in string 011565.

I solved this by reading it as an int and calling toString on it.

`Map(p => p.TimeclockCode).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<int>(0).ToString());`
Which gave me desired results of 11565.

Am I missing something about the implementation of fluent mappings?
Where is the leading zero coming from?

Comment: How is TimeclockCode defined in the class? I am looking at the documentation and I don't see anything wrong in what you shared.

Comment: `public string TimeclockCode {get; set;}`

Comment: Are you sure the CSV line doesn't contain the string 011565? How does it look like? I will attempt to recreate this in code.

Comment: The line only contains 11565. When mapping it to a string property the 0 gets added unless I pull it in as an int then call toString() on it. It seems like .Index() reads it as an int, then tries to convert it into a string to map to my property, and somewhere a 0 gets added.

Comment: Can you re-create a small contained example of this? Or at least post the CSV line that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your problem. I used this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "\"11565\",\"a\",\"012\",\"4.5\",\"01\",\"555\"\r\n";
    using (var sr = new StringReader(s))
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyClassMap>();
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var record = csv.GetRecord<MyClass>();

        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
    public string TimeclockCode { get; set; }
}

public sealed class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.TimeclockCode).Index(0);
        Map(p => p.Test).Index(2);
    }
}
```

I can only assume that the value in the CSV is 011565 or that you have some other issue that is not evident from the text of the question.

Comment: Whats even more strange than that, putting your code to the test results true if I test it against an int and string  
            `FakeReader r = new FakeReader();
             var arr = r.ResultList.ToArray();
            arr[0].TimeclockCode.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(11565);
            arr[0].TimeclockCode.ShouldBeEquivalentTo("11565");
        }` both tests are green

Comment: But what about the value? Is it "011565" or just "11565"? How is my code different from yours?

Comment: I opened the file in notepad and saw that the value is actually "011565", excel was hiding the zeros. However why does `row.GetField<int>(0).ToString() ` drop the leading zero?

Comment: Because GetField takes the value "011565" and turns it into an integer (because you asked it to) then turns it into a string, thus becoming "11565".